# What's the correct spelling of 'shmare'?

Tags: meaning, spelling

I've heard this expression several times in TV shows, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Is it like a small "piece" of some spread? Can I say for example:

> "**Shmare** me some Nutella"?

Or

> Can I have a **shmare** of Nutella on my toast?

Comment: It is possible that someone who has never spent time in the company of speakers whose parents or grandparents speak Yiddish, but has heard the word on TV, might say something like "Shmear me some Nutella".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats's very helpful! I specifically remember that in The Big Bang Theory someone said just: "Schmear me!"

Comment: The further away you get from the generation that spoke Yiddish, both time-wise and culture-wise, the more likely you will hear **schmear** used like it was a normal English word or perhaps occupying some transitional place where the usages sound funny and the use is intentionally comic.

Comment: I think I found the scene you were talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTZuzJ_k7lA

Comment: W/R/T the Big Bang usage, "[noun] me" is not really grammatical (AFAIK), but is slang for "give me a [noun]", usually asked of a buddy in a friendly and relaxed setting.  In my experience, the only really commonly used noun is *beer*, and the similar sounds of "beer me!" and "schmear me!" makes for a good joke on TV.    If I said e.g. "screwdriver me!", I suspect native speakers would be confused without context, and words that can also be verbs would be even more confusing (e.g. "hammer me!").

Comment: This form where a noun is spontaneously turned a verb is very common in slang-speak and/or among younger people. It's happening all the time now.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add on to Lambie's answer:  As with the Jewish holiday of "Hanukkah" (or "Chanukkah", "Chanukah" etc.) there is no single *correct* spelling for many of the Yiddish words that you might hear in regular conversation.  This is because the words have been transliterated from a language that has sounds that don't appear in English.

The most common spelling I've seen is [*schmear*](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Schmear), because the "sch" combination most closely resembles the Yiddish pronunciation, although most English speakers just say it like the typical "sh".  So *shmear* or *shmeer* would not be incorrect.

There are dozens of similar Yiddish words that have made their way into common English -- *kvetch, glitch, shlep, shmaltz, shmooze, schmuck, spiel* (pronounced "shpeel") and many others.  In some amusing cases the words have become so common that people use them without thinking.  For example *bupkes* (or *bupkis*, or *bubkis*) recently appeared in the Disney children's movie *Moana*, even though the original, literal meaning of "goat excrement" is roughly equivalent to saying "shit".

Comment: Great, Andrew.Thank for adding those common ones. My brain just wasn't bringing them up. You have two that I already mentioned. :) I wonder how many people knew schlong when the current president used it. Public speech is really going downhill with him.

Comment: @Lambie  Well, being a Jewish person whose parents are from New York, I probably have heard them more often than most.  My wife (the shiksa) loves to use Yiddish whenever she can.  As for Trump, I have no love -- but Lyndon B. Johnson was famously foul-mouthed, although less publicly.

Comment: LBJ is a saint compared to this bum. Nussbaum tweeted: Schlong is not a verb even if used by a putz. (not an exact quote but very funny).

Comment: You missed the closely-related words *kitsch* and *tchotchke*. Then there are the insulting politically incorrect ones like *schwartze* and *faygeleh* that thankfully seem to be dying out.

Comment: @CanadianYankee  eh, stop *kvetching*.  It wasn't meant to be a complete list. What a pain in the *tochas*.   :)

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of words of Yiddish origin that have moved over into AmE speech in certain geographical areas and social groups.

Common ones include: schmear (schmeer or shmeer, see below), spiel (a story, as in invented story or tale), schlep (lug things around) and nosh (to snack). There are also some common insults like: putz and schmuck. Schmear (schmeer) is a verb. Please see below. Many are very funny.

A shmuck is an "unintentional jerk" whereas a schmendrik is a "deliberate" one. 
shmuck is very common today. Click on the Jewish Lexicon link below and search for it.

New York and its burroughs are where one hears a lot of this usage. One recent example was the current (orange-haired man) president (who is not at all Jewish but comes from New York City), who actually referred to a politician being "schlonged". I knew the word but had never heard it used as a verb. Many people unfamiliar with the term didn't even realize how funny it was. It means penis, and he meant it as "to be screwed" (to avoid using the four-letter word here).

EXAMPLE SENTENCES from the lexicon link below.
"Let me schmear some sun tan lotion on myself." or" "I'll take a dozen plain bagels and one sesame bagel with a shmeer."

Please note: for a person from a non-Jewish origin such as myself, I take delight in these great words. There are found in the writings of such American Jewish writers as Isaac Bashevish Singer (Nobel Prize for Literature,1978) and Saul Bellow. Many of the terms are rather funny (haha).

Here's a video of the "language of humor": [Yiddish and comedy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GSIwLrG60g)

[Jewish Lexicon](http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/words/478)
[see the creators of the lexicon](http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/about)

Comment: @jamesqf are you sure the schmuck hits aren't because that's the German word for jewelry?

Comment: @DonQuiKong I agree with jamesqf. I'm Jewish and I've always heard it pronounced and spelled as he says.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not saying it's wrong, but the argument with the google hits probably is

Comment: @DonQuiKong If you restrict it to "schmuck german" it's only 17 million. And all the top hits for "schmuck" are the Yiddish meaning.

Comment: @Barmar funny, I get 126 million hits for schmuck and the top ones are all german (obviously). I still think the argument is ... not exactly one with scientific value ;)

Comment: @DonQuiKong Are you German? Google tailors their results to the user.

Comment: @Barmar yes, hence the "obviously"

Comment: @DonQuiKong: Of course I'm not sure, as I didn't take the time to read all 110 million links :-)  But I don't see why Google would be giving me a great many pages in German - or French, Russian, Cantonese, &c.  But the first few pages I skimmed all have the English meaning, while the first few for "smuck" have mostly different meanings, such as Urban Dictionary's "a light smack upside the head" or one of those supposed collective nouns for a group of jellyfish. (Which I think people just make up...)

Comment: @Lambie no it's smuck now! It even will have a Wikipedia article. Just a second ... ;)

Comment: @DonQuiKong The Jewish Lexicon link says: shmuck. So, I actually made two typos, now corrected.